# How are DX and DY coordinates calculated in flash?

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript, gallery, config

I'm trying to update a clients site and the original developer left almost no instructions.  The code is all updated through XML.

Here is a sample of the code

```
enter code here<FOLDER NAME="COMMERCIAL">
    <GALLERY NAME="LOCANDA VERDE: New York">
            <IMG HEIGHT="500" CAPTION="Some photo" WIDTH="393" SRC="locanda1.jpg" DX="60" DY="40" LINKTEXT="" LINKURL="" INFOTEXT="SOHO, NEW YORK"/>
            <IMG HEIGHT="300" CAPTION="Some photo" WIDTH="450" SRC="locanda2.jpg" DX="160" DY="80" LINKTEXT="" LINKURL="" INFOTEXT="SOHO, NEW YORK"/>
            <IMG HEIGHT="500" CAPTION="Some photo" WIDTH="393" SRC="locanda3.jpg" DX="80" DY="260" LINKTEXT="" LINKURL="" INFOTEXT="SOHO, NEW YORK"/>
            <IMG HEIGHT="500" CAPTION="Some photo" WIDTH="393" SRC="locanda4.jpg" DX="120" DY="60" LINKTEXT="" LINKURL="" INFOTEXT="SOHO, NEW YORK"/>
            <IMG HEIGHT="393" CAPTION="Some photo" WIDTH="500" SRC="locanda5.jpg" DX="180" DY="100" LINKTEXT="" LINKURL="" INFOTEXT="SOHO, NEW YORK"/>
            <IMG HEIGHT="500" CAPTION="Some photo" WIDTH="433" SRC="locanda6.jpg" DX="60" DY="140" LINKTEXT="" LINKURL="" INFOTEXT="SOHO, NEW YORK"/>
            <IMG HEIGHT="500" CAPTION="Some photo" WIDTH="393" SRC="locanda7.jpg" DX="100" DY="200" LINKTEXT="" LINKURL="" INFOTEXT="SOHO, NEW YORK"/>
        </GALLERY>`enter code here
```

It relates to this page:  http://meyerdavis.com/ Click Commercial > Click Laconda Verde New York.
The xml file pulls a jpg from 2 places, one is a thumb nail that are all 60 x 60 and then one is the bigger sized image.  The issue that I'm having is that I can't figure out how the DX and DY coordinates are generated for each item.  Any help would be much appreciated.

`

**Edit**:  Here's the code from the comment below.

```
platformblock.expandspeed = 0.02; 
platformblock.h = 450 - platformblock.dy1; 
//platformblock.h = 402; 
platformblock.dy2 = 0; 
platformblock.onResize(); 
/**/ 
platformblock.onEnterFrame = function() { 
    this.dy1 += (48 - this.dy1)*this.expandspeed; 
    this.h = 450 - this.dy1; 
    if(this.expandspeed<0.3) { 
        this.expandspeed += 0.02; 
    } 
    if(Math.abs(this.dy1-48)<0.2) { 
        this.dy1 = 48; 
    } 
    if(this.platform._height==402 && this.dy1==48){ 
        this.h = null; 
        this.onResize(); 
        this.onEnterFrame = null; 
    } 
} 
platformblock._resizeto(800, 402, _root.play, _root, 0.08); 
titleblockcontainer.play(); 
/**/ 
stop();
```

Comment: It will be in your code mate, but without seeing the code we can't help you :D

Comment: Hi heartcode, sorry, does that mean that it would be in the flash file?  The XML file only includes what I posted above.

Comment: platformblock.expandspeed = 0.02;
platformblock.h = 450 - platformblock.dy1;
//platformblock.h = 402;
platformblock.dy2 = 0;
platformblock.onResize();
/**/
platformblock.onEnterFrame = function(){
 this.dy1 += (48 - this.dy1)*this.expandspeed;
 this.h = 450 - this.dy1;
 if(this.expandspeed<0.3){
  this.expandspeed += 0.02;
 }
 if(Math.abs(this.dy1-48)<0.2){
  this.dy1 = 48;
 }
 if(this.platform._height==402 && this.dy1==48){
  this.h = null;
  this.onResize();
  this.onEnterFrame = null;
 }
}
platformblock._resizeto(800, 402, _root.play, _root, 0.08);

titleblockcontainer.play();
/**/

stop();

Comment: Please don't post your code into comments like that - it's unreadable and doesn't help others.  Edit your original question instead.  I did this for you this time, please delete the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just looking at the page, I would guess DX and DY refer to the position (from the top left) the thumbnail moves to when you click it, just before the large image is shown.  Try changing some of the values - can you see anything move or appear differently?

Comment: I changed some of the values, and at first I thought the DX and DY values were the place where the thumbnails moved as well, but its not.  I did some changing around with the xml DY and DX values and couldn't figure it out.  The numbers correspond to the way that the image resizes, but I can find a common formula.